# GRPC SSL on Kubernetes with NodeJS client

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, grpc, nginx-ingress, grpc-node

I have a gRPC server running on my local mac perfectly with a self-signed certificate and I'm able to connect from the NodeJS client code as well as from the Postman gRPC client ( Beta ). But, when deploying the same service to Kubernetes with these annotations in ingress -

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "GRPCS"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/grpc-backend: "true"
```

The Postman is able to connect to the endpoint but, my NodeJS client code is not even able to hit the service. Eventually, the NodeJS client is throwing an error -

```
Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses
```

Is there any special trick to apply?

Comment: can you show the nodejs code snipt where the server start? might be it listening on localhost only?

Comment: Hi @Adiii here is the code snippet -

```
server.bind(`${host}:${port}`, rpc.ServerCredentials.createSsl(Buffer.from(serverOptions.__SERVER_CA_ROOT__), [{
                    cert_chain: Buffer.from(serverOptions.__SERVER_CERT__),
                    private_key: Buffer.from(serverOptions.__SERVER_KEY__)
                }];
server.start();
```

Also if I change the hostname from 0.0.0.0 with the host of Ingress the server is throwing error -

 30 server_secure_chttp2.cc:81] {"created":"@1660801568.466275887","description":"No address added out of total 2 resolved"

Comment: Whats the value of host?

Comment: It should be 0.0.0.0

Comment: And for which host the certificate is valid? Why not to terminate ssl at ingress?

Comment: Yes @Adiii you are right the host is 0.0.0.0 and the cert is valid for the ingress host with name poc.my-cluster.ca-tor.containers.appdomain.cloud. Also the business requirement is to provide the TLS cert at the POD level so we can't use the SSL termination on the Ingress. But, I believe the self-signed cert won't work here right ? So to avoid multiple certs I'm trying to use the ingress level secrets to run the server. Not sure fully where am I doing the wrong?

Comment: yes, run the same certs that is used at ingress and set the host `0.0.0.0` it should work

Comment: No @Adiii actually I'm stuck there itself as I am running my grpc server on 0.0.0.0 and the cert valid for poc.my-cluster.ca-tor.containers.appdomain.cloud. So getting the error - 30 ssl_transport_security.cc:1245] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number. when the server starting up and on the client side Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses while placing the grpc call.

Comment: do you really need to specify the host?